# Express the range of a Domain Subset [Notation]

Tags: functions, notation

I got a Function f with Domain A and Range B, if S is a subset of A, how can I express the set of the computed values of s with function f?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(S)$ is a good option.

Formally every function $f:A\rightarrow B$ induces a function $\wp\left(f\right):\wp\left(A\right)\rightarrow\wp\left(B\right)$ by:

$S\mapsto\left\{ f\left(s\right)\mid s\in S\right\} $ for $S\subset A$.

So if ambiguity can arise you could use $\wp\left(f\right)\left(S\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(S)=\{f(s)\in B\ :\ s\in S\}$$  helps.

Comment: you got.. corrected

Answer (score 0):

The term "range" is used somewhat loosely in various circumstances. I have found it useful to distinguish between "range" and "image". Formally, if
\begin{equation}f:A\rightarrow B
\end{equation}
then the domain of $f$ is $A$, the range of $f$ is $B$, and the image of $f$ is $f(A)$.

Enlarging the range of a function results in a different function, even though the domains are the same and the functions assume the same values at each point of their domains.

The main idea here is that a function need not map its domain onto its range. In fact, it does so if and only if the range equals the image. Every function maps its domain into its range and onto its image.

Food for thought.

This may seem like a trivial and pedantic distinction, but you will find it is of the utmost importance in many cases later on.